# Customization of nhibernate <set> querying

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, set, one-to-many, outer-join

I want to get `ClassA.ClassBCollection` property filtered and paged. I need to change filtering dynamically.

The default querying will result in something like:

```
    select * from ClassA 
             left outer join ClassB 
             on id == FK_ClassB
```

Can I customize querying of nhibernate set somehow?

**Mappings:**

```
<class name="ClassA">
    <property name="Name" />
    <set name="ClassBCollection">
      <key column="FK_ClassB" on-delete="cascade" />
      <one-to-many class="ClassB" />
    </set>
  </class>

  <class name="ClassB">
    <property name="Something"/>
  </class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do understand your question...

> Can I customize querying of nhibernate set somehow?

...correctly, the answer is NO.

I mean, if you think about getting the instance of `ClassA` and doing some paging and filtering over its `<set>` collection. That would be always done in memory. *(What we can do with mapping I appended at the end)*.

#### we can change the approach

In this case, when you need a filter and paging over the *collection* items, I would strongly recommend to go the other way. Create `Criteria` (`QueryOver`, `HQL`) not over the `ClassA` but over the **`ClassB`**.

First of all we have to extend `ClassB` mapping:

```
<class name="ClassB">
  <property name="Something" />
  <many-to-one name="ClassA" column="FK_ClassB" fetch="join" />
</class>
```

And then create a `Criteria` like this

```
var criteria = NHSession.Current.CreateCriteria<ClassB>();

criteria
    .Add(new InExpression("ClassA", new object[] {1})) // id of one or more ClassA
    .AddOrder(new Order("Something", true))            // Order By
    .SetFirstResult(2)                                 // Skip
    .SetMaxResults(10);                                // Take

var list = criteria.List<ClassB>();
```

Because we used mapping of ClassA `fetch="join"` the resulting SQL statement will be very similar to the first snippet in this question.

So this way, we can achieve the desired SQL Select, but we cannot use `ClassA.ClassBCollection` directly. We did it this way...

#### NOTE:

*Filters / paging which we can influence on the `<set>` mapping are static filter in the where clause and style of fetching values.*

*Where clause will always be evaluated when loading `ClassBCollection` as a property of the `ClassA`. It could be like `where="IsActive=true"`*

*In case that ClassA can have a lot of items in ClassBCollection, we can manage how they will be loaed. Very effective way is attribute batch-size [documented here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)*

Comment: So it is like a tradeoff: you use ClassA.ClassBCollection or you customized query and have a decoupled from ClassA result collection?

Comment: You got it. I guess that I was in the same situation as you. Large collection, which was not optimal to load lazily. So, when I had the ClassA, I asynchronously went to get a part of its collection...

Answer (score 0):

> Can I customize querying of nhibernate set somehow?

I'm not entirely sure what this means. If you meant, can I query and use WHERE clauses over the collection, the answer is yes. Here's how:

```
[TestFixture]
public class StackOverflowQuestion13496270Tests
{
    public ISession session;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        session = // Get the current NHibernate session
    }

    [Test]
    public void Query_ClassA()
    {
        var results = session.Query<ClassA>()
            .Where( x => x.ClassBCollection.Any( y => y.Name == "Bob" ) )
            .Fetch( x => x.ClassBCollection )
            .Skip( 0 )
            .Take( 50 )
            .ToList();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Query_ClassB()
    {
        var results = session.Query<ClassB>()
            .Where( x => x.Name == "Bob" )
            .Fetch( x => x.ClassAParent )
            .Skip( 0 )
            .Take( 50 )
            .ToList();
    }

    public class ClassA
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ClassB> ClassBCollection { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        // Add this and the appropriate mapping modifications to be able to navigate back to the parent
        public virtual ClassA ClassAParent { get; set; }
    }
}
```